# Python Reason for why certain elements come out as arrays and scalars

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm running a code which basically rotates an large data array (50M Lines) around 3 dimensions. However I have run into a strange problem which I have narrowed down to how the rotation matrices are evaluated. Basically, for any rotation other than around the x-axis, the python code hangs forever (can't even hotkey out of it), i.e, when I attempt to do a large matrix multiplication with np.dot using y/z rotation and data.T.

Strangely, it is absolutely fine when I use the x rotation and it computes fine. Evaluating the form of the matrices separately, it looks like under some certain unknown condition, the y and z rotation matrices return arrays instead of a scalar and I suspect this is interfering with numpy's method of np.dot.

While I can just float all the elements in the rotation matrix and it runs, but I would like to determine the source of this problem. I have attached a sample code adapted from my original code that reproduces this effect. The first set of print produces rotation matrices with scalar elements. The second set of print statements produces matrices where the x_rotation has scalar elements, but y,z rotation has an 1x1 arrays for non-zero elements

```
import numpy as np

def x_rot(a):
        return np.array([[1,0,0],[0,np.cos(a),-np.sin(a)],[0,np.sin(a),np.cos(a)]])

def y_rot(a):
        return np.array([[np.cos(a),0,-np.sin(a)],[0,1,0],[np.sin(a),0,np.cos(a)]])

def z_rot(a):
        return np.array([[np.cos(a),-np.sin(a),0],[np.sin(a),np.cos(a),0],[0,0,1]])

ang1 = np.random.choice([-1.,1.],1)*((np.pi/4.*np.random.random()) + np.pi/6.)

print x_rot(0.1)
print y_rot(0.1)
print z_rot(0.1)

print y_rot(ang1)
print x_rot(ang1)
print z_rot(ang1)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you do `np.random.choice([-1.,1.],1)`?

Comment: Hi, i'm just creating a random angle for my rotations that is somewhat substantial (away from pi, pi/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to choose a scalar with `numpy.random.choice`, don't specify the `size` argument. Specifying a `size` of 1 causes it to generate a length-1 1-dimensional array.

Comment: I'm still confused to the reason why the x_rotation interprets ang1 as a scalar while, y,z considers it a 1x1 array. 

In addition, I've also added a [0] at the end of ang1, and it produces "TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'". Doesn't this suggest that ang1 is a float object?

Comment: @kevenren: No, it suggests that the thing you're indexing is a float object. Indexing has lower precedence than multiplication, so you tried to index one of the factors you multiplied together to produce `ang1`, rather than indexing `ang1`.

Comment: `x_rot` happens to produce the result you wanted due to obscure details of how `numpy.array` guesses the intended dtype and shape of the array and how it coerces the input.

Answer (score 1):

When `a` is a scalar, all 3 `rot` produce a (3,3) array.

When `a` is the (1,) array produced by your random.choice, the `x_rot(a)` still produces a (3,3), but the others produce a (3,) object array

```
In [157]: a
Out[157]: array([-0.8658327])
In [158]: np.array([[np.cos(a),-np.sin(a),0],[np.sin(a),np.cos(a),0],[0,0,1]])
Out[158]: 
array([[array([ 0.64800612]), array([ 0.76163512]), 0],
       [array([-0.76163512]), array([ 0.64800612]), 0],
       [0, 0, 1]], dtype=object)
In [159]: np.array([[np.cos(a),0,-np.sin(a)],[0,1,0],[np.sin(a),0,np.cos(a)]])
Out[159]: 
array([[array([ 0.64800612]), 0, array([ 0.76163512])],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [array([-0.76163512]), 0, array([ 0.64800612])]], dtype=object)
```

Evaluating just one 'row' we get

```
In [160]: np.array([np.cos(a),0,-np.sin(a)])
Out[160]: array([array([ 0.64800612]), 0, array([ 0.76163512])], dtype=object)
```

that mix of `np.cos(a)` and `0`, 'confuses' `np.array`, and it falls back on producing an object array.

`rot_x` starts with `[1,0,0]`, which, in some sense 'sets the tone' for the rest of the array.  It's the complex issue of how `np.array`  handles inputs with mixed dimensions.  Can it create a nice 2d array, does if fall back on making an object array, or will it throw an error?